# How to output to two columns in Powershell with XML

Tags: arrays, regex, xml, powershell, split

I have a simple menu to run some tasks, the menu reads variables through an xml config.

At the moment it outputs to screen like this:

1. App One.
2. App Two.
3. App Three.
4. App Four.

However I would like to output it like this (due to menu getting larger):

1. App One. 3. App Three.
2. App Two. 4. App Four.

Can you look at this code and advise how I can implement the above?

```
[xml]$Config=@"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Menu>
    <Head>
    Dashboard
    </Head>
    <Actions>
        <Id>
            <Option>1</Option>
            <Description>App One</Description>
        </Id>
        <Id>
            <Option>2</Option>
            <Description>App Two</Description>
        </Id>
        <Id>
            <Option>3</Option>
            <Description>App Three</Description>
        </Id>
        <Id>
            <Option>4</Option>
            <Description>App Four</Description>
        </Id>
    </Actions>
</Menu>
"@

    foreach ($Item in @($Config.Menu.Actions.Id))
    {
        Write-Host ("{0}.`t{1}." -f $Item.Option,$Item.Description)}
```

Would I need to use maybe split/regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will add a newline character (`` `n ``) to the menu string if the item count is even. Meaning you will have two items on each line of your menu.

```
$c = 1 
$menu = ""

foreach ($Item in @($Config.Menu.Actions.Id)) {

    $menu += ("{0,2}.`t{1,10}." -f $Item.Option,$Item.Description)
    If($c % 2 -eq 0){$menu +="`n"}

    $c++
}

Write-Host $menu
```

Using `-f` you can format your columns to a set size, the following formats `$Item.Option` to have a 2 width and `$Item.Description` to have a width of 10 characters.

```
"{0,2}.`t{1,10}." -f $Item.Option,$Item.Description
```

Comment: Hi, that does the job thanks, just need it formatted a bit nicer, so that there is a tab between the two columns or they are aligned a slightly neater?